# Why in this PDF file generated in this example my watermark is not displayed?

Tags: python, django, reportlab

Why in this PDF file generated in this example my watermark is not displayed? How can I fix it? (There is no error, just does not display "WATERMARK".)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/#outputting-pdfs-with-django

```
import xhtml2pdf
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
import reportlab
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def delivery_cancel(request, did):
    d_instance = get_object_or_404(Delivery, pk=did, user=request.user)
    users = request.user.get_profile()
    user = request.user
    contents = render_to_string('delivery_cancel.html', {'delivery':d_instance,'users':users,'user':user})
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=mypdf.pdf'
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(contents.encode('utf-8')), result, show_error_as_pdf=True, encoding='UTF-8')
    x = canvas.Canvas(pdf)
    x.drawString(100, 100, 'WATERMARK')
    x.save()
    response.write(result.getvalue())
    result.close()
    return response
```

**EDIT:**

```
def delivery_cancel(request, did):
    d_instance = get_object_or_404(Delivery, pk=did, user=request.user)
    users = request.user.get_profile()
    user = request.user
    contents = render_to_string('delivery_cancel.html', {'delivery':d_instance,'users':users,'user':user})
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=mypdf.pdf'
    content_stream = StringIO.StringIO(contents.encode('utf-8'))
    x = canvas.Canvas(content_stream)
    x.drawString(100, 100, 'WATERMARK')
    x.showPage()
    x.save()
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(content_stream, result, show_error_as_pdf=True, encoding='UTF-8')
    response.write(result.getvalue())
    result.close()
    return response
```

Now watermark is missing and looks like that `pisaDocument` not working because PDF format looks different. (or I did something wrong again)

Comment: I think you are missing ``x.showPage()`` before ``x.save()``.

Comment: @niekas Thanks, but still seems not work :(

Comment: I think, that ``canvas.Canvas`` constructor accepts byte stream, not ``pisa.pisaDocument`` instance. Try ``x = canvas.Canvas(result)``.

Comment: @niekas now I have only watermark, without pdf file content :)

Comment: @niekas Do you know another solution to add here watermark?