# Why in this PDF file generated in this example not able to add watermark Pyhton3

Tags: django, python-3.x

Why in this PDF file generated in this example not able to add watermark . How can I fix it? (There is no error, just does not able to display "WATERMARK".).

```
template_name = assign_custom_template(template_name)
template_path = template_name
e_library_list = Elibrary.objects.get(pk=e_library_id,)
retrun_questionlist = {}
for e_library_question_list in e_library_list.products.all():
    questionlist = MCQAnswerFiled.objects.filter(group__pk=e_library_question_list.id)
    retrun_questionlist[e_library_question_list.id] = questionlist
context = {'e_library_list': e_library_list,'retrun_questionlist':retrun_questionlist}
# Create a Django response object, and specify content_type as pdf
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'
# find the template and render it.
template = get_template(template_path)
html = render_to_string(template_path, context)
response = BytesIO()
file = open('sheetstudentcopy.pdf', "w+b")

pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), file,link_callback=link_callback)



file.seek(0)
pdf = file.read()
file.close()            
return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

Comment: Please provide information on which library you're using to generate PDFs

Comment: import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa

Comment: The watermark is not added in your code because there are no instructions present that would be doing it. The code looks like a raw assignment, with blank lines to fill with the implementation. Have you tried any solutions on your own before asking?

Comment: yes i have tried  link given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838212/why-in-this-pdf-file-generated-in-this-example-my-watermark-is-not-displayed

Answer (score 1):

You should include the watermark image directly into your CSS template, as described in the documentation:

https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#page-background-image

For example:

```
@page {
    background-image: url('/path/to/pdf-background.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I want to add text

Comment: Then add text to your watermark JPG, it's the easiest way considering the amount of effort you're putting into this. Otherwise, consider seriously revising your question and adding the actual code you tried.